# typescript jquery focusin unbind event doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I have a focusin binding inside a class. I've tried the jQuery `unbind` method. Seems not to work.

This is just an example :

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="text"/>
    </body>
</html>

module TheClass {
    export class MyClass {
        private static focusHandler = () => { console.log("hello from log"); };

        public static bindInput() {
            $("input").bind("focusin", MyClass.focusHandler);
        }

        public static unbindInput() {
            $("input").unbind("focusin", MyClass.focusHandler);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works just fine :

```
module TheClass {
    export class MyClass {
        private static focusHandler = () => { console.log("hello from log"); };

        public static bindInput() {
            $("input").bind("focusin", MyClass.focusHandler);
        }

        public static unbindInput() {
            $("input").unbind("focusin", MyClass.focusHandler);
        }
    }
}
// Call both functions and it works:
TheClass.MyClass.bindInput();
TheClass.MyClass.unbindInput();
// i.e. nothing in the log. 
// Remove the second and I can see the log
```

Perhaps call the two functions?

Compare:

http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/su7JW/10/ <- you can see the log

http://jsfiddle.net/basarat/su7JW/11/ <- nothing logged

Only difference is the call to `MyClass.unbindInput();` in the second fiddle. The JS is generated from [TS playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=module%20TheClass%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20export%20class%20MyClass%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20private%20static%20focusHandler%20=%20%28%29%20=%3E%20%7B%20console.log%28%22hello%20from%20log%22%29;%20%7D;%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20static%20bindInput%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24%28%22input%22%29.bind%28%22focusin%22,%20MyClass.focusHandler%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20static%20unbindInput%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%24%28%22input%22%29.unbind%28%22focusin%22,%20MyClass.focusHandler%29;%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A//%20Call%20both%20functions%20and%20it%20works%3a%0ATheClass.MyClass.bindInput%28%29;%0ATheClass.MyClass.unbindInput%28%29;)

Comment: do not work if the function is declared inside the bind function itself. Right now i unbind all without hanlder. thats ok to me.

Comment: @Abc that is actually mentioned in the unbind documentation : http://api.jquery.com/unbind/ `Even though the two functions are identical in content, they are created separately and so JavaScript is free to keep them as distinct function objects. To unbind a particular handler, we need a reference to that function and not a different one that happens to do the same thing.`